# How can I change navbar to tabs using CSS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change navbars to tabs using CSS, I know there are angular-ui that I can use but I want to implement this using CSS. Any help will be appreciated in this regard.

**main.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div >
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.dit">DIT</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.st">ST</a>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.uat">UAT</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a>PROD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes of "Bootstrap Tabs" if you want and change CSS according to your need.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

Here's the code